# CAA issuewild multi-level sub-sub-domains

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard-subdomain, caa-record

CAA probably makes sure that issued certificates come from my CA and not from another one.

Given in the DNS:

```
example.com. 300 IN CAA 0 issue "ca.example.com"
example.com. 300 IN CAA 0 issuewild "ca.example.com"
```

Question 1: Can my CA use it to issue the following sub-subdomains?

```
a.b.c.example.com
d.e.f.example.com
```

Question 2: If this is not possible, what is the easiest way to do this in DNS? We have many sub-subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CAA specification includes DNS walking up the root.

So first a DNS query for CAA record at `a.b.c.example.com` will be done, and if this fails, then same query for `b.c.example.com`, then `c.example.com`, etc. until a match is found or the root is reached.

See [RFC 8659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8659.txt) §3 that shows the algorithm to be used:

```
  RelevantCAASet(domain):
    while domain is not ".":
      if CAA(domain) is not Empty:
        return CAA(domain)
      domain = Parent(domain)
    return Empty
```

with this explanation:

> The search for a CAA RRset climbs the DNS name tree from the
>      specified label up to, but not including, the DNS root "." until a
>      CAA RRset is found.

So answer to your Question 1 is yes, and hence question 2 disappears.

Comment: With reservation: It looks as if my CA is not RFC compliant. By the way: With wildcard certificates you can only assign one subdomain level (right?) and with CAA you can "assign" many sub-subdomains.

Comment: "With wildcard certificates you can only assign one subdomain level (right?) "  Correct.

Comment: It looks like I need to convert dots to hyphens. I don't know what this is supposed to do. Where can you complain? Sure, my CA should first become RFC-compliant. But why are there no wildcard certificates that allow multiple deeply nested subdomains?

Comment: I didn't follow you on "It looks as if my CA is not RFC compliant." as I do not know what you mean. If you have other questions please open a new separate post on the site.

Comment: "But why are there no wildcard certificates that allow multiple deeply nested subdomains? " Same problems as cookies in the web. One can not know when an administrative boundary is crossed (it is not automatically a dot).